# Как привязать текст c помощью Binding из richeditBox по паттерну MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

Как привязать текст из RichEditBox к свойству ViewModel по паттерну MVVM ?
У TextBox например есть свойство Text={Binding MyText}. А как это сделать в RichEditBox ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102981/6808809